# Print only timestamp and message in journalctl

Tags: systemd, logs, arguments, journalctl

I'm trying to get the last few lines from `journalctl` so I can feed them into my `conky`. However `journalctl` by default provides too much crap that wastes space: With `journalctl -u PROCESS -n 5 --no-pager -l` I get entries like:

`DATE TIME HOSTNAME PROCESS: MESSAGE`

I want to print only `TIME MESSAGE`. How can I do that?

---

The manpage says there's an `-o` argument, but there's no predefined format that fits my need. I tried adding `--output-fields=__REALTIME_TIMESTAMP,MESSAGE` but that just shows the default output (and not timestamp/message). That argument claims only some formats are affected, so I tried `--output-fields=__REALTIME_TIMESTAMP,MESSAGE -o verbose` but that only gives me the normal vebose output. Besides, apparently there's 4 fields that are always printed, which is already too many for me. I want just 2: a compact timestamp and the message.

I could use some bash magic or a python script to clean it up, but that seems a bit excessive. Surely there's a way to ask journalctl to give me just a timestamp and message?

Comment: 3 years later, trying to achieve the same behaviour. The `--output-fields` option is just ignored. Have you solved the issue?

Comment: @Maximko , have you tried `--output="json" --output-fields="MESSAGE"`, i.e. specifying `output` explicitly? It works for me where without, `--output-fields` is indeed ignored. The docs read: *Select fields to print in **verbose/export/json modes***. The default is *short*, so it doesn't work there.

Comment: I solved the issue using python bindings for systemd, and periodically generating a text file which contains the last 20 lines from journald, formatted as I need (including colored fields, etc.) with conky syntax. I then just read periodically this file in conky.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT**: Please refer to [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/761385/24283) instead. The below answer is kept only for posterity.

---

This seems to have been implemented in 2018, see [this PR](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/pull/7181). With version 236 and above it looks like you can use `--output-fields=`, described in `--help`. Check your version with `systemctl --version`, my CentOS 7 currently (in 2019) runs version 219 so this will probably take some time to make it out to most environments.

**edit**: FYI EL8 (as of 2021-04-12) runs systemd 239, so this is available.

Comment: This is not a qualified answer and only hints at where the answer may be.

Comment: As the documentation for `--output-fields` says that `__CURSOR`, `__REALTIME_TIMESTAMP`, `__MONOTONIC_TIMESTAMP`, and `_BOOT_ID` are always printed, I don't see how this is an answer to the question.

Comment: @Kusalananda - well, not always - not when using `-o cat`, though there's a catch here, see my answer. I assume this post was made in good faith, at a time when these options were not properly implemented, nor properly documented and not even available on most platforms - which means it should have been a comment. From what I gather, as I wrote in my post, the answer is clearly "no", the `--output-fields` option cannot produce the output the OP desires.

Comment: I have edited the answer to refer to the answer written by @don_crissti instead. Please stop using this comment thread for discussion.

Answer (score 4):

`journalctl --output cat`

```
cat
               generates a very terse output, only showing the actual message of each journal entry with no metadata, not even a timestamp. If combined with the --output-fields= option will output the listed fields for each log
               record, instead of the message.
```

Comment: This doesn't print the timestamp as requested by OP.

Answer (score 3):

> Surely there's a way to ask `journalctl` to give me just a timestamp and
> message?

No. As of now (November 2023) there's no way to have `journalctl` print just the time and the message without post-processing.
The closest to what you want is

```
journalctl --no-hostname -o short-full
```

which will give you `DATE TIME PROCESS: MESSAGE`
If that's not good enough for you then your only option is to use other tools to extract / format that data.
With `journalctl` you could use one of `json` or `export` output modes, extract only the timestamp and message (and convert the timestamp to time only) - like user *deanresin* [shows here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/761243) via `jq`.
You could also use one of the `systemd` bindings available and write your own tool to get that data, as suggested by user *Maximko* in comments (e.g. [`python systemd.journal`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/python-systemd/journal.html))
Finally, if you wanted to display the messages in real time, you could use `journalctl` in `follow` mode and prepend a timestamp each time a line is printed e.g. with `ts` from `moreutils`:

```
journalctl -f -o cat | ts '%H:%M:%S'
```

---

Now, as to why `--output-fields=__REALTIME_TIMESTAMP,MESSAGE` doesn't print only those two fields...

The [current manual page for `journalctl`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/latest/journalctl.html), section "Output Options" states:

> --output-fields=
> A comma separated list of the fields which should be included in the output. **This has an effect only for the output**
> **modes which would normally show all fields** (verbose, export, json,
> json-pretty, json-sse and json-seq), **as well as on cat. For the**
> **former, the** "__CURSOR", "__REALTIME_TIMESTAMP",
> "__MONOTONIC_TIMESTAMP", and "_BOOT_ID" **fields are always printed**.

`--output-fields` was added in version 236, however support for filtering fields when using `-o cat` [was only added later, in version 246](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/blob/main/NEWS):

> journalctl's "-o cat" output mode will now show one or more journal
> fields specified  with --output-fields= instead of unconditionally
> MESSAGE=. This is useful to retrieve  a very specific set of fields
> without any decoration.

Based on the above, *those four fields are always printed except when using* `-o cat`. One would think that

```
journalctl -o cat --output-fields=__REALTIME_TIMESTAMP,MESSAGE
```

should work... but that prints

```
Failed to get data: Invalid argument
```

Why is that?
The journal fields are described in the man page [`systemd.journal-fields`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/latest/systemd.journal-fields.html#). There are three timestamp fields for messages: `_SOURCE_REALTIME_TIMESTAMP`,`__REALTIME_TIMESTAMP` and `__MONOTONIC_TIMESTAMP` (note that the last two start with two underscores). All of them are in microseconds, formatted as decimal strings so none of them meets your requirement (`HH:MM:SS` format). Furthermore, per the same man page, the last two timestamps are special addressing fields (they cannot be used as matches by which to filter the entries):

> During serialization into external formats, such as the Journal Export
> Format or the Journal JSON Format, **the addresses of journal entries**
> **are serialized into fields prefixed with double underscores. Note that**
> **these are not proper fields when stored in the journal but for**
> **addressing metadata of entries**. They cannot be written as part of
> structured log entries via calls such as `sd_journal_send(3)`. **They may**
> **also not be used as matches for** `sd_journal_add_match(3)`.

The last sentence points to [`sd_journal_add_match(3)`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/latest/sd_journal_add_match.html#) man page which states:

> `sd_journal_add_match()` adds a match by which to filter the entries
> of the journal file. Matches applied with this call will filter what
> can be iterated through and read from the journal file via calls like
> `sd_journal_next(3)` and `sd_journal_get_data(3)`. Parameter data must
> be of the form "FIELD=value", where the **FIELD** part is a short
> uppercase string consisting only of 0–9, A–Z and the underscore; **it**
> **may not begin with two underscores** or be the empty string.

hence the error: `__REALTIME_TIMESTAMP` is not a valid field name for `sd_journal_get_data(3)`.
To sum up: the only timestamp that `--output-fields` accepts when used together with `-o cat` is `_SOURCE_REALTIME_TIMESTAMP` and even then, the output is pretty far from what you want e.g.

```
journalctl -o cat --output-fields=_SOURCE_REALTIME_TIMESTAMP,MESSAGE
```

prints

```
1699815974366491
Supervising 9 threads of 6 processes of 1 users.
1699815968034836
[system] Successfully activated service 'org.kde.powerdevil.backlighthelper'
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not convinced it is possible to full fill your requirements using only `journalctl`, `--output`, and `--output-fields`.

You can use the `--output=json` option of `journalctl` and then pipe that to `jq`.

`jq` is the linux json processor. You can install with `sudo apt install jq`.

The available fields for `--output-fields` option are not documented.  You can get all the available fields by..

`journalctl -n1 --output=json | jq 'keys'`.

You can get the timestamp and message only,

`journalctl --output=json | jq '.__REALTIME_TIMESTAMP, .MESSAGE'`

From there you can format/process further how you want.  I would recommend looking at the documentation for `jq`, `man jq`.

For example, to get timestamp in human readable you can..

`journalctl --output=json | jq '(.__REALTIME_TIMESTAMP | tonumber/1000000 | strflocaltime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")), .MESSAGE'`

Further, to remove formatting of json and put all on one line like journalctl then..

`journalctl --output=json | jq -r '[(.__REALTIME_TIMESTAMP | tonumber/1000000 | strflocaltime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")), .MESSAGE] | @tsv'`

Comment: +1 though note that the fields are quite well documented, see my answer.

Comment: In my `man journalctl` only some fields are mentioned in passing.  There is no exhaustive list.

Comment: @deanresin the exhaustive list of fields is found here [systemd.journal-fields](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/latest/systemd.journal-fields.html#User%20Journal%20Fields).